# Please can anyone help explain to me the meaning of the following codes?

Tags: php, if-statement, session-variables

Please help me understand the following codes:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['StaffId'])){
    $_SESSION['StaffId']="";
}
?>
```

does it mean if there is not a set of StaffId, set it to null?

Comment: `this code initialize a session variable called StaffId` no matter 10 different ways from sunday you cut it. that's what it do. If you don't know what it means to initialize a variable maybe you need to learn some basics of programming.

Comment: nope, it sets `StaffId` element of `$_SESSION` array to empty-string if it was previously set. To set it to `NULL` you need to assign `NULL` to variable like `$_SESSION['StaffId'] = NULL;`. To unset (destroy) variable use `unset($_SESSION['StaffId']);`.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, I think you meant 'if it **wasn't** previously set'.

Answer (score 3):

It's checking to see if the key `'StaffId'` exists in the `$_SESSION` array.

For example, if you have an array:

```
$person = array( 'name' => 'george', 'age' => 22);
```

Then `isset($person['name'])` will return true but `isset($person['height'])` will return false.

So your code sample sets `$_SESSION['StaffId']` to `''` (an empty string), but only if that key has not been set yet for `$_SESSION`.

Edit: it's worth noting if you didn't know already that `$_SESSION` is a variable with special meaning in PHP, [see the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: Finally at least *someone* bothers to explain what a session variable is (or at least it *would* be good if they explained it instead of just linking to the docs).

Comment: i don't think it was a question to begin with, the question was around isset and the logic around that

Answer (score 1):

It simply checks to see if `$_SESSION['StaffId']` is set.

If it is not then it sets it to "" which is an empty string not null

Answer (score -1):

isset - Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

If a variable has been unset with unset(), it will no longer be set. isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL. Also note that a NULL byte ("\0") is not equivalent to the PHP NULL constant.

If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.